# DateTime doesn't accept format or culture when deployed to a virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

I am exporting a string formatted DateTime to a SQL Server record from my ASP.NET(vb.net) application. This works well on my development machine. I can use any formatting and change the culture in either the web.config or my <%@ Page %> declaration.

If I deploy the application to my production server these settings are disregarded. The date time will always be generated in this format "May 7 2014 7:31PM". No culture setting and no toString format shows any effect.

I am not so much fussed about the exact format but I need to get the seconds in the DateTime string. This just seems impossible on the production server.

Edit:

There isn't much code to show. The following line is working fine on the development machine:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff")`

The point is that no format is ever applied on the production server.

Changing the culture doesn't have an effect neither (on the production server).

Edit:

In the page declaration I use:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" Culture="es-MX" UICulture="es" ...
```

In the config I use:

```
<system.web>
<globalization culture="es-MX" uiCulture="es"/>
```

Comment: Please show your code if you'd like help.

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff")

Comment: You may also care to show exactly how you're attempting to use the culture within the page declaration or web.config - if you'd like an answer along those lines.

Comment: Please note that this is not a biggie. As a workaround I generate a timestamp in javascript which I pass with the ASP user login to the database. The time doesn't have to be exact. I just need a way of monitoring user activity (in milliseconds) for certain processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than relying on configuration, consider changing your code to pass a specific culture.

For example:

```
yourDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Or

```
yourDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff", New CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments below, I can offer the following advice:

- Culture isn't relevant for this scenario.  SQL Server doesn't store dates as strings, it stores them in types like `datetime` or `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`.  These types have no culture-specific attributes.
- You should never pass dates as strings when using SQL parameters.  Pass them as `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` types.
- You probably don't need to pass it at all, as you can just use `GETDATE()` or `GETUTCDATE()` in SQL.
- I *think* what you mean is that when you look at the value in another tool like SQL Server Management Studio that you're seeing the output in a string with a particular format.  That format has nothing to do with what is actually stored, only with how it is *displayed*.  SQL has it's own settings for controlling that.

Comment: (Aside) - Also consider that [`DateTime.Now` does not belong in a web application](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Comment: I already tried this previously to no effort. No culture configuration seems to be applied. Neither from the config, nor from the page declaration or directly from code. On the development machine the datetime tostring will always be the same.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at this output?  Are you literally just dumping the string to the response - or perhaps you are assigning it to some control that is then doing something else with it?

Comment: i pass the value to a variable in an SQL insert statement. cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTCHANGE", DateTime.Now.ToString

Comment: i don't think that this has any effect since i can see the right or wrong value in the SQL statement before it is sent.

Comment: Please note that I have done this several times before without ever encountering this problem. The only difference is that I deploy the first time to a virtual Azure machine.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort. I can see this now in SSMS. This is so strange though. The SQL field is declared as varchar() not datetime. Yet SQL still displays the timestamp value as a formated date. Even more bizarre. When I run from the dev server the field stores just the timestamp, but from the production server it still stores a formated date, no matter what. Need to do a bit more reading up on this.

Comment: please ignore last comment. i forgot to recompile on the other server. been looking at this for too long. i have this working now with the timestamp. i know that datetime shouldn't be stored as a string. in this particular case i use the sql table as a datasource for a web feature service and i can't get this service to run with anything else but dumb string values for the moment. marked your answer as correct since i learned a lot.